# Columns does not change for Datatable on click of outside input (while data changes)

Tags: javascript, datatable

On click of an input/button, the data in the Datatable changes but the columns does not.

I am trying to update the Datatable based on different sets of data, on click of specific input/button.
While data updates, the columns does not.

Please find the working example code below,

https://jsfiddle.net/vyz07113/497wyeLg/6/

JS,

```
var olddata = [["COL1","COL2","COL3"],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

var datatablevar;

function showdata(data) {
  var headerRow = data[0];
  var noOfth ='';
  for (var colNo=1; colNo <=headerRow.length; colNo++){
    noOfth += "<th>"+headerRow[colNo-1]+"</th>"; 
  }
  $('#table').append('"<thead><tr>"+' + noOfth + '+"</tr></thead>"');

  data.shift();

  if(datatablevar != undefined) {
    /* datatablevar.clear().draw() */;
    datatablevar.destroy();
  }

  datatablevar = $('#table').DataTable({
    "data": data,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc"]],
    "order": []
  });
}
showdata(olddata);

$('button#change').click(function(){
    var newdata = [["COL4","COL5"],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]];
    showdata(newdata);
});
```

HTML,

```
<button id="change">Another Data</button>
<br>
<table id='table'></table>
```

Expected is that while the new data does get updated in the Datatable, the columns should as well but does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check DataTable's [documentation of destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) first.

Change your function as below suggest should fix your problem:

```js
function showdata(data) {
  var headerRow = data[0];
  var noOfth = '';
  for (var colNo = 1; colNo <= headerRow.length; colNo++) {
    noOfth += "<th>" + headerRow[colNo - 1] + "</th>";
  }

  if (datatablevar != undefined) {
    /* datatablevar.clear().draw() */
    ;
    datatablevar.destroy();
    $('#table').empty()
  }

  $('#table').append('"<thead><tr>"+' + noOfth + '+"</tr></thead>"');

  data.shift();

  datatablevar = $('#table').DataTable({
    "data": data,
    "aaSorting": [
      [0, "asc"]
    ],
    "order": []
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. $('#table').empty() works, as per documentation.